# Commendation system for new users

Tags: feature-request, new-users, badge-request

## TL; DR

Create a new badge, or a few new badges, which could be awarded via voting by high rep (3k+) users to recognize a particularly good first question.

---

Consider our "new" on hold system. High rep users read a question and make somewhat (necessarily) subjective determinations about the content. When 5 users recognize undesirable patterns (primarily opinion based, request for code with no minimal understanding, etc), the question is placed "on hold" with very positive language encouraging the OP to improve their question.

Many, perhaps most, of the questions placed on hold are posted by relatively new users. The new close reasons were created to better address their confusion when first encountering our unique system and culture. (Presumably, more experienced users would have a better sense of why their question was closed.) You could almost say that the close reason overhaul was predicated specifically on the need to help new users.

Occassionaly I've come across new users, some posting for the first time, who have shown an outstanding regard for those very things. They have clearly taken the time to review "How to ask" and have put considerable effort into making their first (or perhaps second) question acceptable.

I got to thinking... what if we had something like close reasons, but on the other end of the spectrum? A special "commendation" badge (or series of badges) reserved for new users (<100 rep, first question, etc) that could be voted on and awarded by high rep users (3k+, for example) recognizing the OP's efforts.

**Our current voting system is excellent** at awarding high quality questioners and answerers with enhanced experiences and privileges. This badge would obviously not replace that system, but would rather complement it by recognizing and pointing out the superior qualities of a specific question posted by a new user. The badge should not be visible on the question itself as the site is primarily about content, not users - it would just be a nice way to say "good job" to a newbie.

We already award badges based on objective criteria, such as number of upvotes, number of views or number of flagged comments. These badges would be unique in that they would be awarded on more subjective grounds based on content.

We could have a single, simple "commendation" badge for a good first question, or we could have several badges recognizing different aspects of a good question. Whether one badge or several, each could be awarded only once and only to relatively new users. (Jon Skeet has enough badges already.) A minimum of 5 votes from users with close priveleges would be required to award the badges.

If we went with a series of badges, examples might include:

- **SSCCE Master** - Based on your first draft, or without being asked, you've described the specific problem exceptionally well and included valid code to reproduce it.
- **No Dummy** - Based on your first draft, or without being asked, you've demonstrated more than a minimal understanding of the problem, included attempted solutions, thoroughly described why they didn't work, and described the expected results.
- **Tubthumper** - After posting an initially poor quality question, responded to comments and dramatically improved the quality of your post.

Comment: A vote is a vote is a vote. We all start with 1 rep. What's TL;DR?

Comment: @Yve - Too Long, Didn't Read.

Comment: I don't understand how that fits with the context of your post? I am not intending to be difficult, just truly don't understand

Comment: @Yve - If a vote is a vote, then why have badges at all? A: To encourage certain kinds of behavior. A badge to award a new user taking the time to understand our system seems appropriate, but could only be awarded subjectively - thus the suggestion.

Comment: @Yve - TL;DR is a summary for people who don't want to read the entire post.

Comment: ok thnkx for that, I didn't realise, I am drafting a post for discussion which addresses your comment about badges ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189010/mission-statement-or-guideline-for-stack-overfow in answer to your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do agree that rewarding new users is a good idea, however I see some issues here.

**SSCCE Master** - Firstly, all badges exist across all Stack Exchange sites, so the SSCCE Master would be unachievable / inappropriate on many sites - think of the Arqade site for example - asking whether or not you can use a bucket in minecraft to carry animals around isn't the sort of question you can answer with a worked example.

**No Dummy**  - This is going to be very hard to programatically detect whether or not a question posed has been well researched or not. Basically, all that could be done is to ensure the question is of sufficient length or not, and that doesn't really check anything.

**Tubthumper** - There are people who go out of their way badge gaming. This badge basically encourages such people to post a bad question so they can get comments and improve it. I wouldn't like to see *any* intentionally bad questions posted on any of the stack exchanges sites.

So basically, I think the intention is a good one, but I don't think these badges are the right way to go about it.

Comment: As I said, the badge is unique in that it could only be awarded via voting by high rep users. It would be to award the OP for subjective qualities which can not be detected programmatically. It would also only be available to low rep users, perhaps only a first question, so I doubt it would be an easy target for anyone interested in gaming the system to get a badge.

Comment: I wasn't aware that all badges exist across all site. That would definitely limit the viability of this idea.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Another issue is that while these badges might *reward* good behavior, they wouldn't be effective in *encouraging* it. New users won't be familiar with how these badges work unless they've spent a good amount of time lurking on the site. We could put a description in the How to Ask page, but it's already long enough, and people already skip it! Basically, this is something that only new users could win and only established users will have heard of.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Good point. The first time a user asks a question, we could have a little sidebar with somthing like "Win the following badges! SSCCE Master for...". But that's probably a little much.

Comment: Another thing I'd forgotten - people are still upset that they can't earn the [beta badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=beta+badge) as it is basically just sat there in the badge list teasing people that they can't get it. We'd just get loads more questions on MSO about *'It's not fair, I can't earn the New User badges while noobs can and I want them...'* posts.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: New users [already ignore most of the page when they ask a new question](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/10/treating-user-myopia.html). Throwing more stuff at them, especially unnecessary information about badges, won't just be ineffective: it'll detract attention from the more important information (formatting help, How to Ask, etc) on the page.